# Casting Powerapps to Chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast, powerapps

I'm using Powerapps to link different O365 features together per meeting to help aggregate notes. I'd like to put an iPad in the conference room and be able to display different drawings and meeting notes on the TV screen. I can make the app, but is there any way I can have the ability to add a "Cast" button to cast the app to the TV screen?

Thanks!

(Here's a concept of what I'm looking for)
[image: Concept]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. A potential work around for you might be:

- Install Chrome on the iPad
- Setup Chromecast
- Open the **browser** version of your app in Chrome
- Then cast from the browser

The experience won't be the same as the app version, but it just might work.